# MySQL Users table separation (Ruby on Rails and Authlogic)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, authlogic

I was wondering if it would be better to have things like `perishable_token` (used for account validation and resetting of passwords), `banned` (boolean to check if the user is banned), `email_verified` (boolean to check if user's email has been verified) in a separate table in the database, as it will rarely ever be used.

Also, I have my applications set so that a user logs in with a password and email address. The email address will only ever be displayed on the User Edit page, and the password will never be displayed anywhere. As these two things will pretty much only be used when the user logs into their account, is it necessary to have them in the main User table in the database? Or would it be better (faster?) to have them in another table?

The user table will have -many- other things that will be displayed on all pages and will need to be checked often (things such as a user's "money" "credits/points" "logged_in?" "badges" etc).

Answer (score 0):

Since your user table has many other things, it seems unlikely that you would get any performance improvement by moving those five columns (which seem not to contain much data) into a separate table.